# How to setup aptdcon to stop asking confirmation in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt

Using aptdcon from a script is useful to avoid collisions between 2 scripts updating a linux box at the same time. The problem is that this line:

`sudo aptdcon --install "python-virtualenv"`

It is asking for confirmation:

`The following NEW package will be installed (1):
  python-virtualenv
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`

It used to work fine (without asking for confirmation) on Ubuntu 14.04.

How could I make it work in a non-interactive way?

Answer (score 2):

https://askubuntu.com/a/231859/117318 answered here.

```
yes | aptdcon --hide-terminal --install "package"
```

Hide Terminal is needed, else piping yes will cause issues. – whitehat101 Mar 17 '16 at 17:58